# Connected Sets and Intermediate Value Property

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

$f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. If $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a number strictly comprehended between the maximum and the minimum of $f$ in M, then $M - f^{-1}(c)$ is not connected.

I think i need to use the property of Intermediate Value, but i don't know how.

Comment: $\{m: f(m)>c\}$ and $\{m: f(m)<c\}$ is  a disconnection of $M\setminus f^{-1}(c)$

Comment: @geetha290krm how can i show the sets of the disconnection are open?

Comment: They are inverse images under $f$ of $(c,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, c)$.